# Force text to stay on one line

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a situation where I have two sections of text that are horizontally adjacent (and contained within an `<li>`).  There is a title with normal justification and then a distance floated right.  I want these to stay on the same line no matter what.  Ideally, the 'title' section would utilize an `overflow:ellipse` and the 'distance' section would be displayed in place no matter how narrow the screen size.

So,

```
|----------------------------------|
|This title is too lo...  4.9 miles|
|Short title              2.4 miles|
|...                               |
|----------------------------------|
```

I've tried several ways to accomplish this, including using `display: table`. I have been unable to achieve exactly this result. This is what I have at current:

HTML:

```
   <li <?php echo $theme; ?>>
     <a href='#' onclick="load_page('<?php echo $listingurl;?>')">
        <span class='container'>
          <span class='name'>
            <?php echo $name;?>
          </span>
          <span class='distance'>
            <?php echo $distance;?>&nbsp;mi</span>
          </span>
        </span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

less/css:

```
.container {
  display: table;
  > span {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}

.name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.distance {
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `HTML`?

Comment: Show you relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: `ellipse` is not a valid value for `overflow`. I believe you meant `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.

Comment: @hungerstar yeah, I manually typed this in to make a simplified example. It's correct in my code.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mekuzacotu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @ZoltanToth So the solution is a fixed width on the distance elements? I can probably make that work...

Comment: @lmerry213 you can make those fluid too (e.g. 25%) just need to adjust the calculation of the `.name`

Comment: @ZoltanToth This is working well for me. If you want to post as an answer I will accept. Thank you!

Comment: @lmerry213 your question is closed - nobody can post an answer. That's why I put my solution just as a comment. But you're welcome to use it without accepting if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `white-space: nowrap;`?

```css
li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="title">The Title Is Kinda Long I Guess</span>
    <span class="distance">4.5 miles</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lu64d6w5/

Comment: this works if the second span element isn't floated right. I need it to be on the right side, and be visible no matter how much the first element has to cut itself off.

Comment: Can the second span have a defined width?

Answer (score 1):

Just play with **white-space** rule.
Try to give this CSS rule to the container:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

According to W3:

> nowrap: Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single
>   whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues
>   on the same line until a 
>  tag is encountered

Comment: This will do it.  Additionally you can get a cool "..." to show automatically by setting a width on your element and using a combination of the overflow and text-overflow rules.

Comment: I have been playing with this. I think the problem is that it doesn't apply to floated elements;